# Message: Return value of getRefundPaymentMethods() must be of the type array, string returned

Tags: php

```
private function getRefundPaymentMethods(array $invoices, bool $hasUpgrade): array
{
    $refundMethods = [self::CREDITS];

    if ($hasUpgrade) {
        return $refundMethods;
    }

    $transaction = $this->wsTransRepository->getPaymentTransactionByInvoice($invoices[0]['invoiceId']);
    $originalPaymentMethod = $transaction->gateway;
    $dateTransaction = strtotime($transaction->date);
    $now = time();
    $timeDiff = $now - $dateTransaction;
    $diffDays = round($timeDiff / (60 * 60 * 24));


switch ($originalPaymentMethod) {
        case strstr($originalPaymentMethod, self::BRP_CREDIT) && $diffDays <= 330:
            $refundMethods[] = self::BRP_CREDIT_1X;
            break;
        case self::DIL && $diffDays <= 90:
        case self::PLP:
        case PlpConfig::GATEWAY:
            if ($diffDays <= 180) {
                $refundMethods[] = $originalPaymentMethod;
            }
            break;
        **case PxConfig::GATEWAY:
            return $refundMethods[] = $originalPaymentMethod;**
    }

    return $refundMethods;
}
```

I need to return two values, the one in $refundMethods and the one in $originalPaymentMethods.

I tried to use str_split but I couldn't bring the two values

Comment: `return $refundMethods[] = $originalPaymentMethod;` - the return value of an assignment expression is the _assigned_ value. You are returning a string value here, because `$originalPaymentMethod` is a string.

Comment: Yes, but I need to return the $originalPaymentMethod which is a string, and also the $refundMethods which is an array. I would need the return of these two values.

Comment: Ok. But you are misunderstanding how return works, as CBroe has just explained. Again, you're returning the _assigned value_, because you returned with an assignment statement (not just a single variable). Assign the value to $refundMethods and then **separately** return $refundMethods.

Comment: Why put a return in _that_ place to begin with? You are not looping anything here, so your switch statement executes only once anyway. This is your last case, and _after_ the switch, you are doing `return $refundMethods;` anyway. So why not _just_ add the entry to the array at that point.

Comment: Actually, you don't need even `return` in `return $refundMethods[] = $originalPaymentMethod;`. Just put `$refundMethods[] = $originalPaymentMethod;` (as you did in the previous case) and then the `return` statement at the end of the function will catch it and return the value. No idea why you used `return` inside the `switch` there, it's completely inconsistent with how you've written the rest of the function. Stick to some coding standards, review your code, get someone else to review your code...that'll help you as well.

Comment: Thanks guys, it's really not making sense. I managed to adjust, I'm a starter and I'm going to review these concepts. Thank you for your help :)

Comment: Here's a simple demo of the concept: https://3v4l.org/cXkfH . Can you see why the first test returns the integer value 2? It's the value of $y. You assigned $y to the return (as well as assigning it to a new index in $x). In the second test it returns $x because you assigned that to the return.